# Why does the Haggadah interpret ביד חזקה as referring to דבר?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, plagues-makkos, va-eira, hands-fingers, ki-tavo

Why does the Haggadah interpret ביד חזקה (strong hand) as referring to the plague of דבר (pestilence)?  Why don’t the other plagues demonstrate a strong hand?

Comment: Maybe it's trying to allude to the other mention of דבר in the story, namely in Shemot 5:3 פֶּן-יִפְגָּעֵנוּ, בַּדֶּבֶר אוֹ בֶחָרֶב

Answer (score 7):

Each plague was done with a finger of Hashem, as it says "אצבע אלקים היא" (Shemos 8:15) by כנים, and דבר was the fifth plague, making it 5 fingers, a full hand.

(my) Source: Maaseh Nisim Hagada by Rabbeinu Yaakov m'Lisa (aka the Nesivos Hamishpat) quoting "the commentaries"

---

While I was looking back through my Haggadas for the source, I found this as well:

The Haggada attributed to the Malbim quotes a Medrash (Shemos Rabba 10:2) that with every plague that came upon Mitzrayim, there was an accompaniment of דבר.  Therefore this plague was inclusive of all the plagues, and is more than just a "finger" like the other plagues.

Answer (score 6):

[The Haggadah explicitly learns](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15765&pgnum=31) that the Hand of G-d refers to Pestilence from [Shemot 9:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9870#showrashi=true&v=3), where it talks about Pestilence coming from the Hand of G-d.

---

Of interest is [Shemot Rabbah 10:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&pgnum=281), which quotes R' Yehoshua ben Levi's teaching that each of the 10 plagues came with a side-plague of Pestilence.

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested that this was the Egyptians first encounter with a plague that’s objective was to bring about death.  It demonstrated Hashem’s ability to bring about life and death.

(I will try and locate the Rishon that said this.)